# Microsoft Access ODBC Connection Strings Limited to 255 Characters?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2003

Microsoft Access 2003 database (.mdb) containing a linked table which connects via ODBC to a backend Microsoft SQL Server 2008 table.

When I enter design view for the linked table, then view the Properties field, I can only see the first 255 characters (specific fields replaced with hyphens):

```
ODBC;Description=------------------------------------;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=----;APP=--------------------------------;WSID=---------;DATABASE=------------------;StatsLog_On=Yes;StatsLogFile=--------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I print the DAO field using the VBA Immediate Window (table name ommitted: "print CurrentDb.TableDefs("-----------").Connect"), I see a prefix plus 254 characters (prefix "ODBC;Description=" plus 254 characters, plus, presumably, a one-byte null character):

```
ODBC;Description=------------------------------------;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=----;APP=--------------------------------;WSID=---------;DATABASE=------------------;StatsLog_On=Yes;StatsLogFile=------------------------------------------------------------------;Trusted_Co
```

How do I view the entire text of the ODBC connection string?

We experience an issue where the SQL Server server logs show error "Login failed for user "{user}". Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: {ip address}]"

I am attempting to confirm the full string "Trusted_Connection=Yes" is part of the stored string.

Comment: Looks like there may not be a way. Command "print RIGHT(CurrentDb.TableDefs("-----").Connect, 10)" displays "Trusted_Co" :o(

Comment: Although this may explain why Windows Authentication is not getting used? I am re-linking with a DSN connection string < 255 characters.

Comment: Just noted one additional observation: the Properties field shows 255 characters, including "ODBC;Description=" prefix, while the Immediate Window displays 254 characters past "ODBC;Description=". So, in both cases, seems like I am hitting the 2^8 limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a 255 character Microsoft Access (2003/2010) limitation on the ODBC connection string.

I removed the ODBC references to StatsLog ant re-linked all the tables within the Microsoft Access database. It has been one week and the DBA team reports no further server log errors.

Answer (score 3):

Update for Access 2016:

Max length of connect string for

- Linked tables: 513 chars
- Pass-through queries: 255 chars

(OP asked about Access 2003 but this question is the only one on this topic.)

Answer (score 0):

Try Shift-F2. That's the keyboard shortcut throughout Access for the Zoom box, and it works in most properties as well.

Comment: This displays only the first 255 characters. Good idea, though!